# PHP Facebook SDK - possible to automatically refresh token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-sdk-4.x

Currently I'm able to get an access token by asking user to log into Facebook and accept my app. 
I can also get a long-term token, but what if that app should automatically retrieve data (images) after months?

Is there a way to store a token and ask for a new one without manual user intervention?

I work in **PHP**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens can only be refreshed on user interaction, after 60 days (when the Extended User Token is not valid anymore) you can´t access any data anymore, unless the user visits your App again.

Comment: Thanks. Then can't I neither simulate an user call in some way? Is pretty a bummer: Google API allows to sistematically refresh tokens

Comment: no, you can´t simulate it. that would make the whole point of short-living tokens pointless. if a user did not use your app for more than 60 days, your app should not be able to get his data anymore.